# How to start docker container using shell script inside the AWS EC2 Container Service?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have docker image and follow these steps https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-1#/firstRun
and pushed docker image to the aws ec2 container service repo.After that
My container needs shell script to start the docker container.but i could not find any place to execute my shell script.
can you tell me correct way to running docker image using shell script inside the AWS EC2 container service.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a shell script to start your container? ECS provides this out of the box when you properly configure a task definition and a task to run on one of your clusters. Your container should start running automatically once all of the resources are properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to keep things self contained. I have like 20 env variables that are configured in a bash script file setting up the --env's for the container. So for me it will be great with just one liner like "./run-app.sh" thats set up --env's and runs it. But its not possible with ECS?
/Morten